# Embedding URL in Ruby Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, layout

I'm having a bit of an issue linking to a web app in my Rails application. Basically, I have a layout for the application, made of a header, sidebar, and main_content, and I want to be able to open the web app in the main window, sort of like a frame would do. How do I go about this? I tried using a simple link_to command, but that opened a new window, even when I included the **:target** parameter. I tried to set up a controller for it, and use that, but I couldn't find a way to link it to the app. Note that while I do own the app, I can only access it through a URL: I don't store it locally.

Sorry if this is an amateurish question, I'm still learning rails, and I'm very much in the beginner stage.

Comment: What does your `link_to` call look like? It shouldn't open in a new window *unless* a `:target` option is specified.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the link you're using is to a full webpage rather than a fragment that's designed to be used inside another page, your best bet is an iframe embed.

All `link_to` does is render a regular hyperlink, and that will always load a new page (whether it's in a new window, tab, or replaces the current page).